# Proof of weak law of large numbers using testfunctions

Tags: probability-theory

How would I prove the weak law of large numbers using test functions $u:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that are continuous and bounded?

I would like to prove that $$ \mathbb{E}[u(\overline{X}_n)]\to u(\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}_n]), as\ n\to\infty.$$
Any suggestions how this could be done?